# Need to build custom horizontal scroll like youtube suggested topic

Tags: lightning-web-components

We all have seen below horizontal scroll in YouTube. I wanna make this scroll using LWC component but yet not proceed much as I am newbie in salesforce and LWC world.
Any Idea? I tried using Element.scrollLeft and Element.scrollright but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hello Saddy and welcome to the community!

Than can be easily done using a flex container with the overflow-x: auto property. We can use the slds classes of slds-grid and slds-crollable_x to get this css properties.

Here is an example

HTML

```html
<ul class="slds-grid slds-scrollable_x">
    <template for:each={badges} for:item="badge">
        <li key={badge.id} class="slds-m-right_x-small">
            <lightning-badge label={badge.label}></lightning-badge>
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

JS

```js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {

  /**
   * Getter for the features property
   */
  get badges() {
    return [...Array(10).keys()]
      .map((_, index) => 
        ({
          label: `Badge - ${index}`,
          id: index,
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Check this live example!

https://webcomponents.dev/edit/EQUiyeFsXxmzyKCvrGlb/src/app.html

[image: Horizontal Scroll Example]